# How to remove a connected action?

Tags: xcode

Learning iOS development and followed the tutorial on Apple's web site. After I have connected a button to the view controller code (by ctl-drag), I decided to rename the action. Instead of refactoring, I removed the section of code and reconnect (by ctl-drag). Now the app crashed everytime I tried to run it because it is still looking for the old action.

How do I resolve this situation instead of creating a new project?

I am using Xcode 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove action in this manner here you will find two action like this already connected to old one so just remove that and it will disappear and connect to new one[image]

Answer (score 5):

First Select your button for storyboard
Then Click on "Show the Connection Inspecter " button on most right size

[image: Show the Connection Inspecter]

Then click on cross button for action you want to remove .

[image: Remove Action]

Answer (score 4):

You can see (X) at the button's connection linked with action in Xib or Storyboard by right click on button. Just click on (x) connected action or IBOutlet are removed and you can connect new or existing action or outlet.

[image]